# How to put all same tags in particular one another tag at a time wherever I used that tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, center

My Html is as follow,

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<label>Name : </label>
    <input type="text" id="user" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button id="submit"> Hit Me !!</button>
</body>

  <p id="id1"> This is paragraph which has id1.</p>
  <p id="id2"> This is paragraph which has id2.</p>
  <button id="change"> To Change Color !!</button>
</html>
```

This is just a small portion of my code and I have lots of button tags in my HTML.
I want to put all the buttons in the center of screen (Horizontally).
I have also created same CSS for all buttons.
So what to write in that CSS, so I can get all the buttons in center ?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? And what has the title to do with _"how to horizontally center buttons?"_?

Comment: While this question is now (currently) closed, please read the "*[ask]*" guidance as to how a good question should be written and presented. It would be worth reading the "*[mcve]*" guidance as well, as - although you've included some of the code you're working with - you haven't provided any CSS that would show your best attempts, and help us identify how to best help you in the most practicable way (in theory, at least).

Answer (score 1):

```
button{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }
```

in your CSS file for all buttons